# Solr highlighting is incomplete

Tags: solr

I searched a word on the solr interface, such as “found”,Its highlighting results are partially missing[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6w7sJ.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSTIa.jpg)

By example I call this URL :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/rds_log_index/select?df=text&hl=on&indent=on&q=found&wt=json
```

I get:

```
 ...},
  "highlighting":{
    "apiv1.rdslog.12":{},
    "apiv1.rdslog.143":{},
    "apiv1.rdslog.154":{},
    "apiv1.rdslog.18":{
      "text":[" not <em>found</em>\\n05-29 10:00:45.993 18659 18659 W ResourceType: No package identifier when getting name",
        " modules: no such module <em>found</em>: com.android.deskclocklib.res20180703\\n05-29 10:00:46.003 18659 18659 W"]},
    "apiv1.rdslog.17":{},
    "apiv1.rdslog.48":{},
    "apiv1.rdslog.139":{
      "text":[" 0x00000000\\n05-31 11:31:18.239 16460 16460 W CtaManagerFactory: CtaManagerFactoryImpl not <em>found</em>\\n05-31 11:31",
        " modules: no such module <em>found</em>: com.android.deskclocklib.res20180703\\n05-31 11:31:18.248 16460 16460 W",
        " modules: no such module <em>found</em>: com.android.deskclocklib.res20190122\\n05-31 11:31:18.252 16460 16460 W"]},
    "apiv1.rdslog.168":{
      "text":["   541 D wifi2agps: scan result, <em>found</em> 4 APs\\n06-05 17:26:23.502   541   541 D agps    : [WIFI2AGPS"]},
    "apiv1.rdslog.172":{},
    "apiv1.rdslog.26":{}}}
```

Its search results are correct, but the highlighting information is missing

Comment: Please include the relevant portions of text (including the request and the response) in your post, and please add details about what you want to have returned - do you want to only highlight the phrase, do the search results show what you want, etc?

Comment: Its search results are correct, but the highlighting information is missing

Comment: What is the matched content in the documents that isn't being highlighted?

Comment: such as：  

"apiv1.rdslog.12":{ "text":[" not <em>found</em>\\n05-29 09:55:46.786 533 951 W MtkCam/TemplateRequest: "]}